# JQuery UI tabs don't render correctly when I load the content by Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have the following html content for a JQuery tab:

```
<div id=tabs >
    <ul>
        <li><a href=#tab1>Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href=#tab2>Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id=tab1>Content of Tab1</div>
    <div id=tab2>Content of Tab2</div>
</div>
```

and I render the tabs by calling following function in my js:

```
function checkerTabs_jqueryui_init(){
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
}
```

Everything works quite fine as long as I place the content, directly in my initial jsp page (not ajax). but if I load the content into page via an ajax call:

```
$( "#tabs" ).load(
        'fetchTabs', null, checkerTabs_jqueryui_init
    );
```

It doesn't render the content as a tab, just simply like a list which no tabs() function is applied on it. the ajax call returns exactly the same html content and the call back function is definitely called, but I don't understand why isn't it rendering correctly.
Am I missing something?

Comment: put this into a jsfiddle so people can play around with it.  you'll get better help this way.

Comment: I found out that the problem is not with ajax, when I call the tabs() function for the first time it works fine, then when I change the contents of the div and call the tabs() again, this time it doesn't render correctly! I don't know why yet, anyway I'm not gonna give up....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself at last. 
the root cause of the problem was calling tabs() on the `<div id=tabs>` more than once. for the first time every thing works fine. but when I loaded the contents of the div again and called the tabs() function again on the div, it didn't work. I still wonder why JQuery is so sentimental about this, but I resolved it by:

loading the `<div id=tabs>` along with the contents every time altogether. I mean loaded the whole div into a `<td>` tag by my ajax load() function which actually resets the state of css classes applied on the div.

so jquery works like the first time, every time.
probably if you remove all the classes applied to `<div id=tabs>` prior to calling tabs() it will work fine as well.

Comment: I had a related problem (tabs did not reload correctly).  I followed an advice I found on SO and did a destroy and init again on the tabs element and that resolved the issue.  Might want to try it instead of full reload.